# Difference between mentioning existential quantifier and not

Tags: quantifiers

Let $n \in N$, Is there a difference between:

1) let us assume as true  $\exists k \in Z / n= 9 k$ and

2) let us assume as true $ n = 9k / k \in Z$?

Comment: Yes: the second one can be read as : $\forall k (x=9k)$.

Comment: What difference would it make in case of induction?

Comment: $∃k (n=9k)$ and  $∀k(x=9k)$ are two different statements, with different meanings, irrespective of the contexts where we used them.

Comment: Is there a way to prove the difference?

Comment: To prove the difference between "$(n=9k)$ for some $k$" and "$(n=9k)$ for every $k$" ? Try with $n=18$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But this according to you is a proposition : a(n) = (n-1) / n in N, right?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a nonstandard notation with this "/" symbol. For instance, it is not listed as a logical symbol in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols), which only lists it as a [division or quotient operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), and every other source I could find with a simple Google search revealed the same usage. Anecdotally, this is consistent with my experience as a student of math: the statements that you've written in the question (and in the Nov. 19 comment) parse as invalid.

However, I am going to exercise some judgement here. It seems reasonable to assume that this symbol roughly means "such that":

(1) Let us assume as true $\exists k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $n=9k$.

(2) Let us assume as true $n=9k$ such that $k\in\Bbb Z$.

The second statement still reads a little awkward to me; if I came across it in a research article I would assume it meant

(2*) Let us assume as true $n=9k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

In this case, (1) and (2*) read to me as the same statement. However, both of these are different from another reasonable interpretation of (2):

(2^) Let us assume as true $n=9k$ for **all** $k\in\Bbb Z$.

In this case, as Mauro mentioned in the comments, (2^) is different from (1), because, for instance: if $n=18$ then $n=9k$ **only** for $k=2$, but there are other numbers $k\in\Bbb Z$ besides $2$, for which $n=9k$ is not true.

Comment: If this answers your question, please upvote or give it "best answer" so that it will be removed from the Unanswered Questions list. If not, please edit your question to use more standard notation.

Comment: That / is meant to mean "for"

Comment: @J.Moh: Hmm, okay. In that case the first sentence strikes me as pretty strange: "There exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ for $n=9k$."? I'm not totally sure why this reads badly to me but my guess is: "X for Y" should be interchangeable with "For Y, [we have] X". But if try that with (1), then you reference $k$ before defining it!